# Grub loading, and restarts

Tags: grub, crunchbang

After installing Crunchbang (3 times now), I start my computer, see "Grub Loading.." 
 
And my computer restarts. 
Tried to load a usb with Grub repair tool, did the so called repair and changed nothing. 
Whats going on?

Note: I do NOT have dual-boot, just Crunchbang.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with your graphics card, since there has been problems like this before outlined at the CrunchBang forum [here](http://www.crunchbang.org/forums):

Click on the looking glass in the upper right to do a search.